# Decoupling angular and the ui thread with web workers, does it work in an upgrade project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, web-worker, angular-upgrade

I came across the possibility to decouple angular from the ui thread to improve frontend responsiveness and performance.

> Usual problem in the typical single-page application (SPA) is that our
>   code is usually run in a single thread. This means that if we want to
>   achieve smooth user experience with 60fps we have at most 16ms for
>   execution between the individual frames are being rendered, otherwise
>   they'll drop by half.
>
> In complex application with huge component tree, where the change
>   detection needs to perform millions of check each second it will not
>   be hard to start dropping frames. Thanks to the platform agnosticism
>   of Angular and it being decoupled from DOM architecture it's possible
>   to run our entire application (including change detection) in a Web
>   Worker and leave the main UI thread responsible only for rendering.
>
> https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist#web-workers

Does this work when we use downgradeModule to run angularjs and angular in parallel? We have a huge application and this could really help us.